# When does the AsyncRestTemplate send request?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

Today I did some experiments on AsyncRestTemplate. Below is a piece of sample code:

```
ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<MyObject[]>> result 
                          = asyncRestTemplate.getForEntity(uri, MyObject[]);
List<MyObject> objects = Arrays.asList(result.get().getBody());
```

To my surprise, the request was not sent to uri in first line (i.e. after calling getForEntity) but sent after result.get() is called.

Isn't it a synchronous way of doing stuff?

Comment: It is starting the request in the first line. (To be precise: it just schedules the request. There is most likely no actual http traffic after that line of code yet.)

Comment: Hi I did some testing today, confirmed that AsyncRestTemplate sends request will get() or addCallback() is called, rather than when getForEntity() or exchange() etc is called.

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea of doing async request is that either you do not want to wait for the async task to start/complete OR you want the main thread to do some other task before asking for the result from the Future instance. Internally, the AsyncRestTemplate prepares an AsyncRequest and calls executeAsync method.

```
AsyncClientHttpRequest request = createAsyncRequest(url, method);
            if (requestCallback != null) {
                requestCallback.doWithRequest(request);
            }
            ListenableFuture<ClientHttpResponse> responseFuture = request.executeAsync();
```

There are two different implementations - `HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequest` ( which uses high performant async support provided in  [Apache http component](https://hc.apache.org/) library ) and `SimpleBufferingAsyncClientHttpRequest` (which uses facilities provided by J2SE classes). In case of `HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequest`, internally it has a thread factory (which is not spring managed AFAIK) whereas in `SimpleBufferingAsyncClientHttpRequest`, there is a provision of Spring managed `AsyncListenableTaskExecutor`. The whole point is that in all cases there is some `ExecutorService` of some kind to be able to run the tasks asynchronously. Of course as is natural with these thread pools, the actual starting time of task is indeterminate and depends upon lots of factor like load, available CPU etc. and should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `future.get()` you're essentially turning an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one by waiting for the result.

It doesn't matter when the actual request is performed, the important thing is that since it's asynchronous, you don't need to worry about it unless/until you need the result.

The advantage is obvious when you need to perform other work before processing the result, or when you're not waiting for a result at all.